# How am I supposed to know that this post is locked when there is no mention of it anywhere?

Tags: support, design, user-interface, locks

I found this post today that obviously didn't belong on Arqade meta, so I was going to downvote and voted to delete as it was already closed. However, when I clicked the downvote button, it said I couldn't vote on a locked post, yet there is nothing anywhere on the question stating that it is locked. How am I supposed to tell that it is locked, when the UI fails to inform me that it is before I attempt to take action on it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

After reading over the question several time, I finally noticed the top box says that the question is no longer accepting interactions.
[image]

Apparently this is the new wording for saying that a question is locked, though I find it much less obvious than it was prior.

Comment: I actually didn't know that a rejected migration caused a lock, but sure enough, [there it is](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/14766/revisions). I wonder if a proper manual lock would have different wording

Comment: @Unionhawk A normal, manual lock would indeed just show "this question is locked" though annoyingly would not show by *whom* in the new post notices unless you click the link into the revision history (or, if there is none, manually editing the URL to get there).